# Is there a Kernel configuration for Simulation KZALLOC Failures

Tags: linux, configuration, kernel

I am trying to test a particular driver.
Would like to simulate KZALLOC() to fail and verify my driver is working fine.
Can anyone recommend a suitable Kernel Configraiton that helps me with this?

I am using 3.10 as well as 3.4 Linux Kernels please/